# Force all traffic through vpn

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

Goal: force all traffic through VPN only.

Client: Windows in VM
VPN: OPENVPN

I delete the 0.0.0.0 route in the client. I make a route for the destination of my VPN server with my LAN default gateway as the gateway (192.168.1.1). So, in practice when I turn on openvpn, it attempts to connect to the server IP which has a route through my local LAN gateway, which would result in a connection and a new VPN connection established. And when the VPN connection drops, all traffic stops.

However, I am unable to connect to the VPN server. I can ping it though. I was able to replicate the same scenario in a windows VM with softether client and a third party VPN and can connect successfully. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: first fix your routing, second, move your question to superuser as it seems to me to be offtopic during its a single solution for one person in a non business environment, third look for the default gateway option in Ovpn